# java jsp get list per selected item

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, jakarta-ee, javabeans

My goal is to get the list of all of the employees per the selected company.
As you can see in the jsp file at the end of the question, I get the error :

```
 {IndirectList: not instantiated}
```

**could you please help me to fetch the list of all employees per selected company?**

Company.java

```
package analysis.data;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Company
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false) 
    private String lastname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)    // LAZY = fetch when needed, EAGER = fetch immediately
    private List<Employee> employees;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Company() {
        super();
    }   
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname.toUpperCase();
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return this.employees;
    }   
}
```

Employee.java

```
package analysis.data;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Company
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable=false) 
    private String firstname;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String lastname;    

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Employee() {
        super();
        //nbAbsences = 0;
    }  

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }   
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return this.company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
        if (!company.getEmployees().contains(this)) {
            company.getEmployees().add(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + this.getId() + "] " + this.getFirstname() + " " + this.getLastname();
    }
}
```

inside my controller.java

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

....

        } else if (methode.equals("get") && action.equals("/detailsCompany")) {
            doDetailsCompany(request, response);
....

    private void doDetailsCompany(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
        Company company = CompanyDAO.retrieveById(id);
        request.setAttribute("company", company);       
        loadJSP(urlDetailsCompany, request, response);
    }
....
```

and inside my CompanyDAO.java

```
public class CompanyDAO {

...

    public static Company retrieveById(int id) {            
            EntityManager em = GestionFactory.factory.createEntityManager();
            Company company = em.find(Company.class, id);
            em.close();
            return company;
        }

...

    public static List<Company> getAll() {
        EntityManager em = GestionFactory.factory.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Company c");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Company> listCompany = q.getResultList();      
        return listCompany;
    }
}
```

and here I choose the company name (id) to be redirected to the detailsCompany to see all the employees of that company:

```
<jsp:useBean id="companys" type="java.util.List<analysis.data.Company>" scope="request"/>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Number of employees</th>
            <th>Employees</th>
        </tr>
    <% for (Company company : companys) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=company.getNom()%></td>
            <td><%=company.getEmployees().size()%></td>
            <td><a href="<%= getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/do/detailsCompany?id=<%=company.getId()%>">See the list</a></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
    </table>
```

and finally inside my `detailsCompany.jsp` JSP file, I am at loss on how to pull the list of employees per company of choice.

```
<jsp:useBean id="company" type="java.util.List<analysis.data.Company>" scope="request"/>

<p>Company : <%=company.getEmployees()%></p>
```

I get this 
     {IndirectList: not instantiated}
instead of the list of employees.
I am not sure if my code is correct in doing so.

Comment: I will read entire question all the evening. Do you have pity on us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

```
`<%=company.getEmployees()%>`
```

getEmployees() returns a List object so JSP invokes its toString function which results in the message "IndirectList: not instantiated"

If you wish to print the employee details (i.e. equivalence of its toString method), you may want to do something like this instead:

```
`<p>Company : <% List<Employee> employees = company.getEmployees();
    for(i=0;i<employees.size();i++)%> 
        <%= employees.get(i);%>
</p>
`
```

You may also want to add some line breaks to separate the various employee records.